# How to consume an Entity Framewok (v6) Library?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I can make an entity framework console application that displays the customers in the Northwind database.

However, when I try to create the Northwind Entity Framework in a separate class library that is consumed by a simple C# console application in a separate sub-project, I encounter some problems.

I read http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=617 
and watched http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff628208.aspx and followed the directions by copying the connection string in the app.config from the library to the console mode program directory and adding a reference to my northwind EF class library.

I'm still getting this exception when trying to create the dbcontext variable in my console program:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
```

After some more google searching I tried adding this code:

```
public abstract class BaseDomainContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext{
    static BaseDomainContext() {
        var ensureDLLIsCopied = System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance;
    }
}
```

The problem now is I get the red squiggly line underneath "SqlServer" -- apparently there is no such namespace in my copy of System.Data.Entry. I just upgraded to EF 6 with nuget. 
Can anyone help me resolve this?
Thanks
Siegfried

Sun Mar 30 2014:
Forgot to mention: I'm using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1. Here is my app.config from my console mode demo program, most of which was copied from the class library app.config. Now that I think about it, who is looking for that connection string? Is it the class library or my console mode demo program? What should be the name of the connection string?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NorthwindEntitiesLib" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=KM;initial catalog=Northwind;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Mon Mar 31 2014:
Everything works fine for VS 2012. I just add the reference to the class library, cut and paste most of the App.config file from the library app.config to the console mode app.config and everything works. What can we conclude from this? Looks like there is a bug in VS2013 with EF 6. Can anyone help me workaround this bug?

Ben: I tried your suggestions and, judging by your XML you posted, it looks like you are using EF 5. I just upgraded to 6. I'm still getting the same errors in VS 2013.

Answer (score 0):

It is in System.Data.dll i.e. `System.Data.SqlClient`.

Make sure you have a reference to this.

Can you post your connection string?

Comment: Here is my app.config -- most of which was copied from the class library app.config

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me - I just created a new project and added a new .edmx file to the project and called:

```
using (YourDbContext db = new YourDbContext(){///}
```

This calls the parameterless constructor for the context which uses the default connection string setting from you app.config.  Take a look at the constructor yourself to see what is auto-generated and you'll see what connection string is being used.

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="NorthwindEntitiesLib" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.Model.csdl|res://*/App_Code.Model.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=KM;initial catalog=Northwind;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
     <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
     </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It works for me too using VS2012. I regret I used nugget to upgrade my VS2013 project from EF5 to EF6. When I pasted your code into my VS2013/EF6 project it did not work because you are using EF5. When I edited the version number to be 6, it still did not work. Is there a way to uninstall EF6 and roll back to EF5 in VS2013?